# How to launch favorite tabs/directories in Terminal.app?

Tags: mac, terminal

If I regularly work with four directories, one tab per directory, is there a way to automate Terminal.app opening these tabs/directories for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set up your Terminal tabs with the correct directories.
2. Choose **Window** → **Save Windows as Group…**.
3. Give the group a name and select **Use window group when Terminal starts**.

   [image]
4. You can open a window group from **Window** → **Open Window Group** → ***named group***, or by restarting Terminal if you selected that option in the previous step.

For more information about Terminal window groups, see Preferences → Window Groups.